# How to update textbox backcolor on button click in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have two textboxes which contains `rollnumber` and `name` and are contained in ListBox. I have button which on each click adds data in textBoxes.

What i want to achieve is when i click on the button then it must change the background color of both the text boxes to green. (Remember on each click to this button i have a new row which adds some text in both of the textbox).

I tried to use triggers but not able to make it yet. Code is below:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="buttonColorChange" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Click, ElementName=btnClick}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>                
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>

        <ListBox Name="empLB" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=emp}" Height="100" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel  Width="300" >                        
                        <TextBox  Name="txt2" Text="{Binding Path= RollNo}"></TextBox>
                        <TextBox  Name="txt1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBox>
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>            
        </ListBox>
        <Button  Style="{StaticResource buttonColorChange}" Name="btnClick" Height="20" Width="100" Content="click On me" Command="{Binding BtnClick}" ></Button>
    </Grid>
```

**How to change the color of textboxes on button click to green?**

Comment: An easy way is just to bind the background colour to a string variable and change it on clicking the button `string colour = "Green"`

Comment: Button does not contain Click property, so your binding inside that style will not have any effect. Apart from that the style should be assigned to textbox and not a button if you want to change the background of the textbox. Just like said above, have a property in your viewmodel and bind to it directly from your textbox. Because that property won't be part of your list you need to use relativesource binding here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the commenters, I'd also put that logic into the ViewModel. Here's an example. I'm using the GalaSoft.MvvmLight nuget package.

View XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BoolToBrushConverter x:Key="boolToColorConv" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ListBox Name="empLB" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=emp}" Height="100" Width="300" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel  Width="300" >
                    <TextBox  Name="txt2" 
                              Text="{Binding Path= RollNo}" 
                              Background="{Binding  Path=DataContext.ContainsItems, 
                                                    Converter={StaticResource boolToColorConv}, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}} }" />
                    <TextBox  Name="txt1" 
                              Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                              Background="{Binding  Path=DataContext.ContainsItems, 
                                                    Converter={StaticResource boolToColorConv}, 
                                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}} }" />
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <Button Name="btnClick" Height="20" Width="100" Content="click On me" Command="{Binding BtnClick}" />
</Grid>
```

View Code:

```
public partial class RollWindow : Window
{
    public RollWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // You might want to replace this with a ViewModel locator
        DataContext = new RollsViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class RollsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> emp
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public bool ContainsItems
    {
        get { return _containsItems; }
        set { _containsItems = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private bool _containsItems;

    public RollsViewModel()
    {
        emp = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }

    public ICommand BtnClick
    {
        get
        {               
            if (_btnClick == null)
            {
                _btnClick = new RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    // Dummy action, replace with call to model
                    emp.Add(new Item() { Name = "A roll", RollNo = emp.Count });
                    ContainsItems = emp.Count > 0;
                });
            }
            return _btnClick;
        }
    }
    private RelayCommand _btnClick;       
}

public class Item : ViewModelBase
{
    public int RollNo
    {
        get { return _rollNo; }
        set { _rollNo = value; RaisePropertyChanged();  }
    }
    private int _rollNo;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private string _name;
}
```

Converter:

```
public class BoolToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var color = (value is bool && (bool)value) ? System.Windows.Media.Colors.Green : System.Windows.SystemColors.ControlColor;
        return new SolidColorBrush(color);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would be great if you could  please explain why we needed to use here relativesource binding ? Is it possible to achieve by just styles and trigger ? I mean a button click triggers the style change of textboxes ? what do you say ?

Comment: RelativeBinding is necessary because we need to go up in the hierarchy level (pseudo-code):
- Window.DataContext (and Window.Grid.DataContext) is set to the RollsViewModel
- Window.ListBox.ItemsSource is set to RollsViewModel.emp
- Window.ListBox.Item[x].TextBoxes in the DataTemplate bind to RollsViewModel.emp[x].RollNo or .Name property

But the ContainsItems property which the TextBoxes shall bind to is a member of the RollsViewModel itself. By going up to the Gird (RelativeSource is FindAncestor with Type Grid) it's possible to bind to the Grid's DataContext, namely RollViewModel.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's impossible to do change a thing in a different GUI Element with styles and triggers, but I doubt so.

The purpose of styles is that its design can be applied to any button you wish, not just 1 button. 
If what you want were possible, which TextBox's background should be set to green if the style is applied to several buttons in a View?

Comment: If it's possible is one question. But another question is where the coloring of the TextBoxes is best placed at. 
Is it just a GUI thing? (E.g. to simply indicate to the user that he clicked the button.) Then I'd place it in the ViewModel as in the example. In MVVM, Views should have as less code as possible. The logic of a View should reside in its ViewModel logic.
Or is it a business logic thing? Then you should follow the BtnClick-Command as it goes into the model. The model logic will change something and that change should propagate into the ViewModel.